# Spring Primefaces. Method/container access don't work

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces, annotations

I'm having an issue when trying to use my controller methods from the page.

I've tried with action and actionListener, and I've mixed these two with ajax="true" and immediate="true" so there are not more possibilities.

At first I'be thought it was not taking the bean, but it does render test attribute.

How could I call these methods?

I know i can use p:url but I'd prefer to use commandButton instead.

My Controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/orderService")
@ManagedBean(name="orderServiceController")
@SessionScoped
public class OrderServiceController implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8694892885365853014L;

    @Autowired
    private OrderService orderService;
    @Autowired
    private OrderContainer container;

    public String test = "test";

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }
    @RequestMapping("/waiterInformed/{tableNumber}")
    public String waiterInformed(@PathVariable Integer tableNumber ){
        log.info("##>> OrderServiceController waiterInformed INI on table " + 
            tableNumber + "<<");
        orderService.waiterInforme(tableNumber);
        return "redirect:/orderService/";
    }
    (...)
}
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">
    <application> 
        <el-resolver>
            org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver
        </el-resolver> 

        <locale-config>
            <default-locale>en</default-locale>
            <supported-locale>es</supported-locale> 
        </locale-config>

        <resource-bundle>
            <base-name>messages.messages</base-name>
            <var>msg</var>
        </resource-bundle>
    </application>

</faces-config>
```

And at last "order.xhtml" mapped in my app-config

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
     xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
     xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
     >
<h:head>

    <script type="text/JavaScript">

        function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
            setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
        }
    </script>


</h:head>
    <h:body onload="JavaScript:timedRefresh(15000);"> <!-- Reload every 15 secs -->

        <h2>#{msg['order.label.title']}</h2>

        <h3>List</h3>
        <!-NOT WORKING (log is not showing any message --> 
        <p:commandButton value="test" action="#{orderServiceController.waiterCalled}">
            <f:param name="tableNumber" value="1"/>
        </p:commandButton>
        <p:commandButton value="test" action="#{orderServiceController.waiterCalled}">
            <f:attribute name="tableNumber" value="1"/>
        </p:commandButton>

        <!-WORKING--> 
        <h:outputText value="#{orderServiceController.test}"/>
  (...)
</h:body> 
</html>
```

Comment: I have no idea how Spring MVC works, but in JSF terms, the backing bean code makes no utter sense. It look much like that you're mixing different frameworks and somehow expecting that they will understand each other. I believe that you're actually looking for PrettyFaces.

Comment: Sorry it took me too much time to answer. I have worked before with Spring and Primefaces and I know it works. I think it is some config issue more than framework incompatibility.